# Navigate on Button Click to Path via React Router 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class-based `App` component in my React app. This component is defined like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
        
// Import pages
import Page1 from './pages/page-1';
import Page2 from './pages/page-2';
    
class App extends React.Component {    
  navigateToPage1 = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    history.push('/page-1');
  }

  navigateToPage2 = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    history.push('/page-2');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container p-3 mx-auto">
        <Router> 
          <div className="pb-2">    
            <button onClick={this.navigateToPage1}>Visit Page 1</button>
            <button onClick={this.navigateToPage2}>Visit Page 2</button>

            <Link to="/page-1">Page 1</Link> 
            <Link to="/page-2">Page 2</Link> 
          </div>

          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Page1 />
              </Route>

              <Route path="/page-1">
                <Page1 />
              </Route>

              <Route path="/page-2">
                <Page2 />
              </Route>    
            </Switch>
          </div>  
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When a user clicks one of the `Link` elements, the app behaves like I would expect. The Page1 or Page2 is shown without refreshing the browser. However, if I click one of the `button` elements, I receive an error that says: "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.". My question is, how do I recreate the same behavior as the `Link` elements in a class-based component?

I am trying to figure out how to do this in JavaScript as I need to navigate to a path via a custom component. The sample code just isolates the issue to demonstrate it. I'm using the following versions:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I recreate the same behavior as the Link elements in a class-based component?

One solution is to define a custom `Button` component and then use that in the `component` prop of the `Link` component.

```
function Button(props) {
  const { navigate, href, children } = props;
  return (
    <button onClick={() => navigate(href)}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

```
<div className="pb-2">    
  <Link to="/page-1" component={Button}>Visit Page 1</Link>
  <Link to="/page-2" component={Button}>Visit Page 2</Link>

  <Link to="/page-1">Page 1</Link> 
  <Link to="/page-2">Page 2</Link> 
</div>
```